# Identity Element and Identity Properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Learning more abstract algebra, really not the most enjoyable of subjects, as nothing seems all that clear cut, but here goes anyway.

I have a set $\mathbb Q = \{{p \over q} : p,q\in \mathbb Z \text{  and  } q \neq 0\}$ which is the set of rational numbers and for $x,y\in \mathbb Q$ defined the binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb Q$ by
$$x*y = x + y + xy.$$

The pair $(\mathbb Q, * )$  has an identity element. Find the identity element then verify the identity properties for $(\mathbb Q,*)$.

Where do I begin?

Comment: You are looking for a rational number y so that in your multiplication formula, everything except for x disappears(so that multiplying by y didn't do anything to x!).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980196/show-that-a-star-b-a-cdot-bab-is-binary-operation-for-the-group-bbb-q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity element $e$ is defined by $x*e=x$ and $e*y=y$ for all $x,y$. Therefore solve the equation

$$x+e+xe=x$$

You get

$$e+xe=0$$
$$e(x+1)=0$$

For this to be true for all $x$,

$$e=0$$

Doing it the other way,

$$e+y+ey=y$$
$$e+ey=0$$
$$e(1+y)=0$$
$$e=0$$

---

You "verify the identity properties" by showing that it is indeed true that  $x*e=x$ and $e*y=y$ for all $x,y$. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: So my identity element would be e = 0. How do I then find the identity properties for (Q, *)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the identity element.

Then $x*y=x+y+xy=x$ for all $x \in Q$.

Now, let $x=0$.  What do you conclude?

Comment: That y = 0. So that is my identity element? What about the properties?

Comment: You're welcome.