# How to show that this is a binary operation?

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let $G = \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$ be the set of all rational numbers other than $1$ and
suppose $*$ is defined as $a*b=a+b-ab$. Show that $*$ is a binary operation on $G$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $a \star b=a \cdot b+a+b$ is binary operation for the group $\Bbb{ Q} - \{-1\}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980196/show-that-a-star-b-a-cdot-bab-is-binary-operation-for-the-group-bbb-q), resp. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184693/prove-that-a-b-a-b-ab-defines-a-group-operation-on-bbb-r-setminus

Comment: [The following is true even when replacing $\mathbb R$ with $ \mathbb Q$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184693/prove-that-a-b-a-b-ab-defines-a-group-operation-on-bbb-r-setminus?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

We only need to show it defines a function from $G\times G\to G$. This follows since $a+b-ab=1$ and $b\neq 1$ \implies $a=(1-b)/(1-b)=1$.

Did you mean group (as opposed to binary) operation?

Comment: Given  G=Q-{1}, a,b ∈G and that implies a≠1, b≠1