# The group $(\Bbb R\setminus\{−10/3\},\ast)$, where $\ast$ is given by $x\ast y = 3xy+10x+10y+30.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For group $(\Bbb R\setminus\{−10/3\},\ast)$, where the operation $\ast$ is given by: $$x\ast y = 3xy+ 10x+ 10y+ 30.$$

> Show:
>
> 1. Group has identity
> 2. each member in group has inverse
> 3. is group abelian?

The problem also states that it is closed under $\ast$ and is associative

I think I understand the properties of each, but don't know how to go about solving. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that $\ast$ is just ordinary multiplication in disguise.

The function $f(x)=3x+10$ defines a bijection $\mathbb R\setminus\{−10/3\} \to \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Moreover, $x \ast y= f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))$. Therefore, the properties of $\ast$ correspond exactly to the properties of ordinary multiplication. In particular, $\ast$ defines an abelian group isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^*$. The group identity is $f^{-1}(1)=-3$.

This technique is called *transport of structure*.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2133694/589

Answer (score 0):

For (1), since the only idempotent of a group is the identity$^\dagger$, solve $x\ast x=x$ for $x$.

> $$3x^2+20x+30=x$$ has solutions $$x=\frac{-19\pm\sqrt{19^2-4(3)(30)}}{6},$$ *i.e.*, $$x=-3\quad\text{or}\quad \color{red}{x=-10/3}.$$

For (2), plug your solution $e$ to (1) in $x\ast y=e$; solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.

> Fix $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \{-10/3\}$. Solve $$3xy+10x+10y+30=-3;$$ that is, $$y=\frac{-10x-33}{3x+10}.$$

For (3), since $3xy=3yx$ and $10x+10y=10y+10x$, the operation is abelian.

---

$\dagger$: Suppose otherwise, that there is an idempotent $y\in G$ such that $y\neq e$. Then $y=y^2$ by definition. Multiply on the left, say, by $y^{-1}$; then

$$\begin{align}
e&=y^{-1}y\\
&=y^{-1}(yy)\\
&=(y^{-1}y)y\\
&=ey\\
&=y,
\end{align}$$

a contradiction.